# reading from /dev/rfcomm0 with bash not noticing file exists

Tags: bash, file, sockets, bluetooth

I am trying to see if the /dev/rfcomm0 file exists but in the way as described below by using the normal [ -f $file ] way I constantly get the message that the file does not exist. But I am able to read the file manually with cat.
looking for /etc/hosts is just for controling that I'm not getting insane.

```
file="/dev/rfcomm0"
file2="/etc/hosts"
while :
do
        [ -f $file2 ] && echo "Found host" || echo "Not found host"
        [ -f $file ] && echo "Found rfcomm" || echo "not found rfcomm"
```

the manual view of /dev/rfcomm

```
root@raspberrypi:~# cat /dev/rfcomm0
```

[null,"0,0,0","255,255,255",5,50,"Nikske"]

Probably I'm missing something very important but I've been looking for a long time after a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-f` flag specifically states in the `bash` documentation (my emphasis):

> True if file exists ***and is a regular file***

So I'd warrant that the file you're looking at is *not* a regular file, especially since it's in the `/dev` directory where all *sorts* of non-regular files tend to exist.

Case in point (on my system with a character-special file):

```
pax$ ls -al /dev/rfkill 
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root netdev 10, 62 Feb 13 17:49 /dev/rfkill

pax$ [[ -f /dev/rfkill ]] && echo regular || echo not regular
not regular

pax$ [[ -e /dev/rfkill ]] && echo exists || echo does not exist
exists

pax$ [[ -c /dev/rfkill ]] && echo char special || echo not char special
char special
```

I'd suggest checking what sort of file it is with `ls -al` and using the appropriate `[[` flag for that (see, for example, `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` in the output of `man bash`).

Comment: I needed a hero. I got a hero. Very interesting. Thx.

Comment: No probs, @Roel. I thought for a minute there you were about to break into a Bonnie Tyler song :-) Showing my age there.

Comment: Everybody Loves Bonnie Tyler. And age is just a number. fyi, rfcomm's a bluetooth socket